# Why padding of parent container is not being applied to floated unordered list?

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML code snippet :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<style>
    *{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }  
    <!--Resetter rules for browsers-->
    #bodyContainer {
    }
    body {
        border:black 2px solid;
        background-color : grey;
        padding:5px;
    }
    #header {
        margin:10px auto;
        background-color : red;
        width:70%;
        height:80px;    
        -webkit-border-radius:15px;
        -moz-border-radius:15px;
        border-radius:15px;
    }
    #header1 {  
        display:inline-block;
        width:50%;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:80px;           
    }
    #header2 {
        display:inline-block;
        width:50%;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:80px;
    }
    #navmenu {
        list-style-type:none;
        background-color:#444;
        border:black 2px solid;
        width:100%;;            
        text-align:center;
        float:left;
        margin-bottom:20px;
    }
    #content {
    }
    #nav {
    }
    #navmenu li {
        border:black 1px solid;
        background:yellow;
        border-radius:5px;
        height:30px;
        line-height:30px;
        width:33%;
        float:left;
    }
    #navmenu li a {
        text-decoration:none;           
        display:block;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bodyContainer">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="header1"><h1>Welcome</h1></div><div id="header2"><h1>You Get to choose better !! </h1></div>           
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="contentHeader">
            <p>You Select ... We Serve </p>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul id="navmenu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Electronics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fashions</a></li>                   
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>WebApp Version Numbered v1.0. All rights Reserved. </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why the floated unordered list seems not to obey the 5px padding at the right edge of the parent container #bodyContainer ? Also is there any efficient way to distribute the floated list items evenly (except from setting it explicitly to Width:33%) as there is an apparent space after the last list item in the floated horizontal navigation list ?

Comment: Try add box-sizing: bоrder-box;

Comment: Element no longer remains the part of normal flow when you make it float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having in regards to your ul being unrespectful of the 5px padding on the body is due to the ul being floated.

```
 #navmenu {
    list-style-type:none;
    background-color:#444;
    border:black 2px solid;
    // width:100%;;            
    text-align:center;
    // float:left;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

For the distribution of the navigation elements, it depends. Whenever you float elements, they stop being contained by other elements. I think what you want to acheive would ask for display:inline-block;

Try this:

```
#navmenu li {
    border:black 1px solid;
    background:yellow;
    border-radius:5px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    width:32%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: that eventually does solve my problem. Thanks for that . But is there any way to make this happen with float:left , actually making display:inline-block expects the list-items to be seated side by side.

Comment: I don't quite understand your end goal. What would you like to happen as opposed to having the li's side by side?